# Drives disconnected from RAID array without apparent reason

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell-poweredge, drac, drive

I have owned a Dell PowerEdge R720 for some time and have been using it as my personal NAS. Here is the RAID configuration (disks in the indicated order) :

- 2 x 146 GB disks in 15K in RAID 1
- 12 x 1 TB disks in 10K in RAID 5
- 2 free slots

I have an ESXi installed on it, everything was working perfectly, but here it is, cracked, one day, the RAID seems corrupted...

Going to the iDrac logs, here is what I found:
[Picture of the iDrac errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noSea.png)

Considering the delays in disconnecting / reconnecting the disks, I strongly doubt that someone from home had fun disconnecting / reconnecting them....

Here is what I see in the VMware VSphere Web Client Interface of my ESXi :

[View from the VMware VSphere Web Client Interface of my ESXi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16cal.png)

What do you think of that?
What could this have to do with?
What can I do to prevent this from happening again?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Considering the delays in disconnecting / reconnecting the disks, I strongly doubt that someone from home had fun disconnecting / reconnecting them` - It takes all of 2 seconds to release the drives and reinsert them... so it could be that someone did just that. Have you tried reinserting the drives?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Yes I did it but now my RAID seems corruped (no boot...) and before shutting it down, the VM were corrupted... :(

Comment: I've added more screenshots to my original post. I think I'll rebuild it in the hope that it will not happen again. Thanks for your help !